# SQL(ite) combining AB with BA groups

Tags: sql, sqlite

The games database has columns of match pairings e.g. country A against B, country C against D, but also country B against A. I need to simply count the number of matches between 2 countries. I can groupby countryA,countryB which results in e.g. this:

```
A B 12
A C 24
F G 2
B A 15
```

Now I need to combine AB and BA to get this:

```
A B 27
A C 24
F G 2
```

I have tried the below query but also realized why it doesn't work. I ran out of ideas.

```
SELECT country_1, country_2, t1.count + t2.count AS count, total 
FROM (SELECT country_1, country_2, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM games
    WHERE tournament_code=?
    GROUP BY country_1, country_2) t1 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT country_1, country_code_2, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM games
    WHERE tournament_code=?
    GROUP BY country_1, ccountry_2) t2
ON t1.country_1=t2.country_2 AND t1.country_2=t2.country_1
```

I feel like there's a very easy solution that I'm missing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy solution, really a nice trick, which you can use here.  You can group by the combination of the "smaller" of the two countries followed by the "larger" of the two countries.  Using this approach, `A, B` would be treated as being in the same group as `B, A`.  Then, aggregate the count over each of these groups to arrive at the result you want.

```
SELECT MIN(country_1, country_2) AS country_1,
       MAX(country_1, country_2) AS country_2,
       SUM(count) AS count
FROM games
 -- WHERE tournament_code = ?
GROUP BY MIN(country_1, country_2),
         MAX(country_1, country_2)
```

It is a useful feature of SQLite that it has a scalar [MIN()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#minoreunc) function, which, given two arguments, can return the lesser of those two arguments (also see [MAX()](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#maxoreunc)).

Comment: Hah, this is awesome. Cheers!